# Passing additional parameters while creating s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Is there a way to pass additional parameters to the AWS API when creating `aws_s3_bucket` resource, namengly `CreateBucketConfiguration/LocationConstraint` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this directly, but you can obtain the same effect through [provider alias](https://www.terraform.io/language/providers/configuration#alias-multiple-provider-configurations) set to a given region:

```
provider "aws" {  
   alias  = "west"  
   region = "us-west-2"
}


resource "aws_s3_bucket" "mybucket" {  
   provider = aws.west
   #...
}
```

Comment: Yeah, this is what I am doing now, but I need to define multiple resources in 17 different regions, and even modularizing this stuff I ended up copy/pasting a lot of repetitive code. I wrote a small script that generates these terraform files, but was hoping for more concise solution.

Comment: @YuriyGalanter How did it go? I don't think you will find any better solution to what you already have.

Comment: Yes I guess this will have to do for now.